# program for multiple of "2" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to code for multiples of the number using javascript. Can anyone help me with the code please.I am very to the javascript code. please help me with explanation
The output should be:

```
2*1=2
2*2=4
.
.
.
2*n=2n
```

Comment: You should give it a try and then post your code here. There are many examples and tutorials available on the internet.

Comment: Hi, Tolokoban - output should be on webpage

Comment: This looks like you're asking us to your programming homework for you :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're totally new in web development. If it is not the case, please don't feel insulted by this answer.

First of all, you need a HTML element to write your output. Let's use a PRE.
Now you need to access it with your Javascript. So your PRE need an `id` attribute to identify it. Your HTML page must then have this line :

```
<PRE id="my-output"></PRE>
```

You can get this element in Javascript with the following code:

```
var pre = document.getElementById("my-output");
```

And to put HTML inside, just use the attribute `innerHTML`, like this:

```
pre.innerHTML = "Hello <b>world</b>!";
```

Now you just need a `for` loop to write each line of your calculus:

```
var n = 10;
pre.innerHTML = "";
for (var i=1 ; i<=n ; i++) {
    pre.innerHTML += i + " * 2 = " + (i * 2) + "\n";
}
```

The `\n` is a line-break that works in a PRE element.

Putting all together, you get this web page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
var n = 10;

function start() {
    var pre = document.getElementById("my-output");
    pre.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i=1 ; i<=n ; i++) {
        pre.innerHTML += i + " * 2 = " + (i * 2) + "\n";
    }
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre id="my-output">Click the button to see the resulting table.</pre>
        <button onclick="start()">Show the table</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course, I hope you have understood all this, and you won't just use it verbatim for your homeworks  ;-)